# Launch Form without a button click

Tags: c#, click, focus

Probably a quick and easy question for someone. Is there a way to create a method that can launch a form (hidden) without a button click. Then focus on the hidden form from a button click on another form. Rough example

method to instantiate FormRating from Form1:

```
private void LaunchRating()
{
 FormRating frm = new FormRating();

}
```

Focus on FormRating from Form2:

```
private void btnTdrEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Show the form
    }
```

I know the examples are rough. I havent actually got anything to work yet. Never done this without a click event so I have no idea, any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you want to launch a seccond hidden form you can use the current form load event to do that

Comment: This is muddy.  You want to start your app, which starts with `LaunchRating` form.  Then you want to have that create a `FormRating` form, and _not show it_?  But then yet another form, `Form2`, is supposed to provide a button click that shows the `FormRating` window?  Is that right?

Comment: What do you expect the user to do if he's not allowed to use the mouse?  Yell at it?

Comment: DonBoitnott, yes you are right. Hans, I want to pass a value to the FormRating using my UserControlForm as an owner. I do not want to show form rating unless the user decides to update something tied to the passed value. if they want to do that they can use their mouse, or yell at it and see what happens.....